# Regular expression to extract text

Tags: java, regex

I have a text like this:

```
 SrcAddr: 0.0.21.201
 DstAddr: 7.202.10.100
 NextHop: 0.33.189.142
 InputIf: 19
 OutputIf: 50715
```

I want to extract the data like this ***using regex***.

```
    String SrcAddr = "0.0.21.201";
    String DstAddr = "7.202.10.100";
    //ect...
```

I've tried with various expressions but still no luck. If somebody can help appreciate a lot

Comment: Can you show what you have tried?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it shows no research effort before posting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this :

```
String input = "SrcAddr: 0.0.21.201\n"+
           "DstAddr: 7.202.10.100\n"+
           "NextHop: 0.33.189.142\n"+
           "InputIf: 19\n"+
           "OutputIf: 50715"; 

String SrcAddr=getMatchedString("SrcAddr",input);
String NextHop=getMatchedString("NextHop",input);
String InputIf=getMatchedString("InputIf",input);
String OutputIf=getMatchedString("OutputIf",input);

System.out.println(SrcAddr);
System.out.println(NextHop);
System.out.println(InputIf);
System.out.println(OutputIf);  

 ..........

 public static String getMatchedString(String word,String input){

     String REGEX = "(?:"+word+":)\\s(.*)";
     Pattern p = Pattern.compile(REGEX);
     Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
     if (m.find()) {
        String matched = m.group(1);
        return matched;
     }
     return null;

 }
```

**OUTPUT**

```
0.0.21.201
0.33.189.142
19
50715
```

**[REGEX DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/sN1tH1)**

Answer (score 1):

```
String input = "SrcAddr: 0.0.21.201\n"+
               "DstAddr: 7.202.10.100\n"+
               "NextHop: 0.33.189.142\n"+
               "InputIf: 19\n"+
               "OutputIf: 50715";

String SrcAddr = input.replaceAll("(?s).*SrcAddr:\\s([\\d\\.]+)\\s.*", "$1");
String DstAddr = input.replaceAll("(?s).*DstAddr:\\s([\\d\\.]+)\\s.*", "$1");

System.out.println(SrcAddr);
System.out.println(DstAddr);
```

Prints:

```
0.0.21.201
7.202.10.100
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this out, it takes your string with multiple lines as input, and spits out the numbers (IP's and ports by the looks of it) line by line.

Since the question itself is the regex, I did not put much effort in the reading process so I just used a scanner, and not bothered in reading/writing a text file, I assume you already got that part.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class MainRegex {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String input = "SrcAddr: 0.0.21.201\n"+
                       "DstAddr: 7.202.10.100\n"+
                       "NextHop: 0.33.189.142\n"+
                       "InputIf: 19\n"+
                       "OutputIf: 50715"; 

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(input);
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
          String line = scanner.nextLine();
          String output = matchString(line);
          System.out.println(output);
        }
        scanner.close();

    }

     public static String matchString(String input){
         String regex = "(?:\\w*: )((?:\\d+\\.?)*)";
         Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
         Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
         if (m.find()) {
            String matched = m.group(1);
            return matched;
         }
         return null;
     }  

}
```

Output:

```
0.0.21.201
7.202.10.100
0.33.189.142
19
50715
```

In the scanner loop you can process the line. I could not understand by your question if you only wanted to get the numbers, or replace each line with String [name] = "[number]". If that's the case, you just have to tamper a bit within the scanner's loop and also remove the non-capturing groups in the regex (that means, remove the "?:" before the \w) so that it captures the words as well.

Hope it helps!

Comment: By the way, using this way you don't need to know the words themselves, like "SrcAddr" and such, beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
    String in = " SrcAddr: 0.0.21.201\nDstAddr: 7.202.10.100\n NextHop: 0.33.189.142\n InputIf: 19\n OutputIf: 50715";

    Pattern src = Pattern.compile("SrcAddr:\\s+([\\d\\.]+)");
    Pattern dst = Pattern.compile("DstAddr:\\s+([\\d\\.]+)");
    Pattern nextHop = Pattern.compile("NextHop:\\s+([\\d\\.]+)");
    Pattern inputIf = Pattern.compile("InputIf:\\s+([\\d]+)");
    Pattern outputIf = Pattern.compile("OutputIf:\\s+([\\d]+)");

    Matcher srcMatcher = src.matcher(in);
    Matcher dtsMatcher = dst.matcher(in);
    Matcher nextHopMatcher = nextHop.matcher(in);
    Matcher inputIfMatcher = inputIf.matcher(in);
    Matcher outputIfMatcher = outputIf.matcher(in);

    if (srcMatcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(srcMatcher.group(1));
    }
    if (dtsMatcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(dtsMatcher.group(1));
    }
    if (nextHopMatcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(nextHopMatcher.group(1));
    }
    if (inputIfMatcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(inputIfMatcher.group(1));
    }
    if (outputIfMatcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(outputIfMatcher.group(1));
    }
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score -1):

Check out this online java regex tester:
http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html

I pasted in your text to 'input 1', then put in the regular expression:

```
\d*[.]\d*[.]\d*[.]\d*
```

Results:

```
[10,20] 0.0.21.201
[32,44] 7.202.10.100
[56,68] 0.33.189.142
```

Don't forget - when you use it in java code, you need to escape the backslashes:

```
"\\d*[.]\\d*[.]\\d*[.]\\d*"
```

Also, here's a fun regex game to help you learn regular expressions:
http://regexcrossword.com/